# how to check set cookie location in java

Tags: java, cookies

I want save cookie in folder to read by another application. for example at `D:/StockData` folder in java.

how can I set cookie path to store at this location in java.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie set path in java using

```
   Cookie c = new Cookie("key", str);
    c.setPath("c/jeni");
    String s = c.getPath();
```

http://candidjava.com/cookie-example-program-using-getpathsetpath-to-getset-the-cookie-path/